# Passing Java objects to restful WS api

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

I'm new to Restful web services and trying to create a Restful Web service api. How do I pass a java object as parameter to a restful API? For example, if i have a pojo object 'foo', how can I pass object 'foo' to a Restful WS API? I went through few Spring tutorials in which @RequestBody was used to pass java objects. Is there any other framework supporting similar feature?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in different ways.

You can, for example, use:

- [Spring MVC + Jackson](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring) - Remember to add jackson-databind dependency to the project
- [RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/)
- [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)

I normally pick Spring MVC, because I'm just used to it in a Spring environment.

Spring MVC Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/restcall", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Object restCall(@RequestBody(required = true) PojoJSONDescriptor desc) throws IOException {
    PojoResponseJSONDescriptor res = new PojoResponseJSONDescriptor();
    res.setName("Test");
    return res;
}
```

Jersey tutorial:

[Jersey tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)

Comment: Thank you :) I searched for example programs to pass java objects using jersey and I wasn't able to find a clear one. Can you help me out with an example for How to pass a java object and receive it in restful service?

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.